# How was Clinton's lie under oath about the Lewinsky affair relevant to the subsequent perjury charge?

Tags: united-states, perjury

My reading indicates that Clinton's outright denial about having the said affair constituted perjury, which is why he was impeached by the House. But it's not illegal to engage in sexual intercourse, so what makes the perjury charge valid?

Comment: You may recall that he embedded his testimony in distractions such as unusual definitions of "sexual relations" and confusing conjectures about how the concept "sexual relations" is defined, by him, Lewinsky, or the ordinary person. Under his definition, his testimony was literally true, which is what matters for perjury.

Comment: wait a minute...if his testimony was ***literally*** true then *why* would that be perjury?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Willfully telling an untruth or making a misrepresentation under oath is perjury; the reason you do so or the substance of it is irrelevant.

It is the act of perjury itself that is an offense and led to the impeachment.

Comment: Right.  It's not a crime to have a red car, but it would be a crime to testify under oath that your car is blue.

Comment: @kbelder Unless you had a genuine belief that it was; if you were unknowingly blue-red colorblind say